# There isn’t a software package called “adobe-flashplugin” in your current software sources

Tags: flash

I am trying to install the adobe-flashplugin on Ubuntu 14.04.

On [Adobe's site](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) I choose the "APT for Ubuntu 10.04+" option.

It opens Ubuntu software Center, but it tells me "There isn’t a software package called “adobe-flashplugin” in your current software sources."

Comment: This is off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [ubuntu.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox or Google Chromium? 
For Google Chrome or Chromium you can do this:

1. open a terminal
2. input "apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree"
3. input "update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install"